# OPC server data mapping to SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, opc

Can someone suggest me few ways to connect and map OPC server data to a SQL database?
I am really new to this OPC server and i am looking for a way or a web service method to map the OPC server to a SQL database. Any kind of suggestions for a start would be really appreciated. I did research on this topic and all i could come up with are few licensed tools to do the job.

Comment: The commercial tools are actually good at this. If they are not good for you, which programming language or tools you want to use, or are you indifferent in this? What do you mean by "web service method"? Which OPC specifications you want to cover (e.g. OPC Data Access, or OPC Unified Architecture, or both)?

Comment: @ZbynekZ: Commercial tools are expensive with their licensing .I was planning to implement .net web services to do that job and I wanted some kind of start with it. Any kind of examples would be really appreciated.

Comment: Still unclear about the structure of your solution. Specifically, the role of a Web service is not explained. Which parts you envision it should consist of, and using which protocol they should interconnect? The Web service should be an OPC client? Which other part will connect to it? Which part will connect to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductive Automation has a product that does exactly this: https://inductiveautomation.com/scada-software/scada-modules/sqlbridge

Full disclosure: I work for IA.